# android mms receiver

Tags: android, mms

I found the default messaging app when receive new mms show the option for downloading the content and after downloading the content get downloaded. But how can we get the image downloading link and identify from the internal db that the mms is not downloaded at and need to show the downloaded option. I receive the data as mention below code .. thanks for your  concern.

```
            byte[] pushData = intent.getByteArrayExtra("data");
            PduParser parser = new PduParser(pushData);
            GenericPdu pdu = parser.parse();

            if (null == pdu) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Invalid PUSH data");
                return null;
            }

            PduPersister p = PduPersister.getPduPersister(mContext);
            ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
            int type = pdu.getMessageType();
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748209/receive-mms-messages-in-android-kitkat